# Programmatically set login-url in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Is there a programmatic equivalent to this XML configuration:

```
<logout logout-url="/logout"/>
```

While I can set the login page url like this:

```
@Configuration
public static class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                 ...
                 .formLogin()
                 .loginPage("/login");
}
```

I can't find an equivalent for logout-url.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957445/how-to-perform-logout-programatically-in-spring-3) may help you.

Comment: So there's no way to just set the logout url? That's all I need really, I don't need to do the actual logout programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `and()`.

```
@Configuration
public static class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                 ...
                 .formLogin()
                 .loginPage("/login")
                 .and()
                   .logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
}
```